# header_image() with CSS

Tags: functions, css, header-image

Forgive my ignorance in the matter, as i've only just started delving into wordpress. But, i was wondering if theres a way to use `header_image()` in CSS.

So, for example my `functions.php` is allowing me to enqueue a php file with the header:

`<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8;"); ?>`

Allowing me to manipulate my theme with it. Now, I want my header image to be editable through the customizer instead of the user having to navigate the CSS files. So for example:

```
.headerimg { 
/* Set a specific height */
height: 700px; 

/* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
background-image: url("<?php header_image()?>");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

/* Styling */
border-top: 3px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 3px solid #0099FF; }
```

This of course, doesn't work, and throws the error:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function header_image() in [filepath]

So, in short - is there some way to accomplish this effect? Or will i have to rely on just using straight up `<img>` elements

Comment: instead of enqueueing it, include the file in header.php between style tags (remover the header).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general, it's not possible to use php in CSS. But you can set background image in php file. Like..

```
<div class="headerimg" style="background-image: url(<?php echo header_image(); ?>)"></div>
```

Then in CSS file using class you can set all the other properties you need like height, width, background-position and so on.

Comment: Generally, i try to avoid using inline styles but it works

Comment: I know it's better to not use inline styles but in this case it's the only way to set a background-image that comes from a php function

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli `header_image()` already echoes the image - use `get_header_image()` to return it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the `header_image()` function like that, you would have to bootstrap the entirety of WordPress from the file that is generating your stylesheet.

A better option would be to stick with a static .css file but extract the dynamic portion for use within `wp_add_inline_style()`. When all is said and done, it might look something like:

```
// Generate inline scripts and styles and attach them to the appropriate script handles.
function my_inline_scripts() {
    // header_image() prints the image - we want it as a string.
    $image = get_header_image();

    // Can be false - it might be better to set a fallback here...
    if ( ! $image ) {
        return;
    }

    // First param should be the handle of your theme stylesheet.
    wp_add_inline_style( 'my-theme-style', ".headerimg { background-image: url(\"{$image}\"); }";
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_inline_scripts' );
```